# React not rendering some components despite calling setState on parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a calculator-type application (i.e. I give it a list of inputs, it performs a calculation on them and displays the results), but for some of the inputs it doesn't update the output when the input changes.  Relevant parts of my code:

```
class Results extends React.Component
{
    constructor (props)
    {
        super (props);
    }

    render ()
    {
        let entries = calculate (this.props);
        return  <div className="results">
                    {entries.map(e => <ResultRow key={e.code} code={e.code} name={e.name} />)}
                </div>;
    }
}
class CircuitRow extends React.Component
{
    constructor (props)
    {
        super (props);
        this.state = props.circuit;
        this.nameChange = this._nameChange.bind(this);
    }
    _nameChange (evt)
    {
        this.state.name = evt.target.value;
        this.setState (this.state);
        if (this.props.notifyChange) this.props.notifyChange (this.props.circuit);
    }
    render ()
    {
        return <tr>
            <td><input className="label" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.nameChange} /></td>
            (more fields deleted as not necessary to demonstrate issue)
        </tr>;
    }
}
class Form extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            circuits: [ 
                { id: 1, name: "circuit 1", ... other fields ... },
                { id: 2, name: "circuit 2", ... },
                { id: 3, name: "circuit 3", ... } ],
            colours: "RBWK",
            nextRowId: 4
        };
        this.notifyCircuitChange = this._notifyCircuitChange.bind(this);
    }

    render ()
    {
        return  <div>
                  <form className='optionsForm'>
                    (working part of form for changing colours removed)
                    <table><tbody>
                      <tr><th>Circuit Name</th><th>Count</th></tr>
                      {this.state.circuits.map ((circuit, i) => 
                        <CircuitRow key={circuit.id} index={i} circuit={circuit} notifyChange={this.notifyCircuitChange} />)}
                    </tbody></table>
                  </form>
                  <Results colours={this.state.colours} circuits={this.state.circuits} />
                </div>;
    }

    _notifyCircuitChange (circuit) { this.setState(this.state); }

}


ReactDOM.render (<Form/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

I've not shown parts of the form that *do* work, including a set of checkboxes that change the contents of the Form.state.colours string -- the results do successfully update when I change those, but when I change the 'name' field of one of the circuit rows, the new name is not displayed in the results table, but the old one stays there.

Any ideas why this isn't updating?

Comment: just want to know whats the meaning of this line: `this.setState(this.state);`
you are updating the state value with previous values ?? how it is working ??

Comment: @MayankShukla - The object is being updated in the other component, but React doesn't notice when it is changed, so I call setState to let it know that the value has already changed.

Comment: i dont think that is required, if you are passing values back to parent and setting the state, it will automatically update the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in this function, you are passing props value from `CircuitRow` component, its like whatever you are receiving from parent, ur are passing same value from child, try this:

```
_nameChange (evt)
{
        let circuit = this.state.circuit;
        circuit.name = evt.target.value;
        this.setState({circuit});
        if (this.props.notifyChange) 
            this.props.notifyChange(circuit);
}
```

One more thing, you need to pass the id back to parent `Form` to change that specify element in parent in this function, because in `Form` component you have an array od `circuits` and u have to update only specific element. Like this:

```
_nameChange (evt)
{
        let circuit = this.state.circuit;
        circuit.name = evt.target.value;
        this.setState({circuit});
        if (this.props.notifyChange) 
            this.props.notifyChange(circuit, this.props.key);
}
```

And in `_notifyCircuitChange` method:

```
_notifyCircuitChange (circuit, id) 
{
    let circuits = this.state.circuits;
    for(let i in circuits){
        if(circuits[i].id == id){
            circuits[i] = circuit;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.setState({circuits});
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This does seem to be a better way of doing it.  It seems I'm getting confused with objects updating themselves and their state not being transferred to their original source (I guess somewhere within React they're being cloned so the connection between multiple instances that I assumed were the same instance is being broken).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have the value of the nameField stored as the state of your CircuitRow component, and every time there's a change, you are updating the same in two places: the state of CircuitRow and that of the parent Form. Instead, I would suggest that you pass the value of the nameField as a prop to the CircuitRow component and display that, everytime there's a change, you should trigger a callback function that changes the same in the parent state.

Your circuits array would initially look like this:

```
[ 
  { id: 1, name: "circuit 1", value: "", ... other fields ... },
  { id: 2, name: "circuit 2", value: "", ... },
  { id: 3, name: "circuit 3", value: "", ... } ]
```

Pass the value to each of the CircuitRow components as a prop, and display this in the render.
On change, trigger notifyChange from CircuitRow, that updates the value in the Form component.